# How can I replace masked pixels by another image

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, masking

How can I replace masked pixels with another image?

I have two sets of images: Image_A and Image_B, each has 10 bands.

I want to change the masked pixels in Image_A by the corresponding (same band, line, and column) values from Image_B.

```js
Image_A_Update = Image_A.updateMask(Image_A.unmask(Image_B))
```

If Image_B also has a mask for some pixels, the output would be the mask for those pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Image_A_Update = Image_B.blend(Image_A);
```

This will be unmasked wherever at least one of the images is unmasked, using pixels from `Image_A` if available and pixels from `Image_B` otherwise.

(This is the same operation as `ImageCollection.mosaic()`, just applied to two images instead of an entire collection.)